# Что происходит если в нити появляется исключения?

Tags: java, многопоточность, исключения

Может кто-то мне детально объяснить что происходит если в нити появляется исключения.Нить просто прекращает свою роботу? И как при этом ведет себя ExecutorService?

Comment: [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread) не плохо описано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае появления не обрабатываемого исключения(`Exception`) или ошибки(`Error`) нормальный порядок выполнения программы прерываться, и исключение или ошибка будут переданы в предусмотренный для этих целей `UncaughtExceptionHandler` обработчик.

Если программист не регистрировал свой обработчик, то будет использован обработчик по умолчанию который напечатает данные трассировки стека в `System.err`.

---

Что касается `ThreadPoolExecutor` то здесь дело обстоит следующим образом, если используется метод `execute` то все ошибки обрабатываются все тем же `UncaughtExceptionHandler` обработчиком, а потоки в которых произошло исключения заменяются на новые.

Но если задача вызвавшая исключение создавалась с помощью `submit` то ошибка полученная в результате работы такой задачи считается частью статуса ее результатов работы. И для таких целей `UncaughtExceptionHandler` обработчик не вызывается, а получить ошибку можно вызвав метод `get` у объекта `Future`. Кроме того, `ThreadPoolExecutor` не будет пере создавать объект потока если исключение возникло у задачи созданной с помощью метода `submit`.